# How to print form input (email) as a mail-able link in PHP

Tags: php

Sorry, I'm still learning! There's this exercise in which I have to create a PHP code that will gets the input --> outputs it as a link if it is an email address --> and if not a email address, outputs it as a string.

I can't seem to link it as an email address. I made the output print a link using , but it just prints $email on the address line. So frustrated. Any help to how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .error {color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Arial'; background-color: #000000; border-radius: 10px; padding:10px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 

        <?php
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$emailErr = "";
$email = "";

if ($_POST) {


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";

    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }


}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
        ?>

        <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 

            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </form>

        <?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";

if ($_POST) {


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";

    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        echo ( '<a href="mailto:$email">Click Me</a>');
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "$email"; 
        }
    }


}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you post a question , its a good idea to remove all the code that has nothing to do with the issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form button is clicked go ahead and check if the email field is not empty. if its empty create error else call the test_input function that does another bit of out.

```
 $emailErr = "";
 $email = "";
if (isset($_POST)) {
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $emailErr = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        }
    }
```

This function does some security stuff but most importantly it uses the filter_var function to check if submitted input is an email. if its an email it sets the email variable above to a link or else it sets it to a string that the user submitted.

```
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        if (filter_var($data, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $result = '<a href="mailto:' . $data . '">Click Me</a>';
        } else {
            $result = $data;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

At this level you dont need to validate anything, all you need is to echo out either the error that was set above if the user submitted empty form or the email variable that was set from test_input function.

```
    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"> 
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>

    <h2>Your Input:</h2>
    <?php echo $email; ?>
```

Comment: It works!! -grovels- Thank you so much! >_< I will analyze this religiously.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ( '<a href="mailto:$email">Click Me</a>');
```

To

```
echo ( '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">Click Me</a>');
```